# React Router: why does nested route make react render on same page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm following this turorial: [React Router Tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/04-nested-routes). In this tutorial, author does 2 things:

Nest children routes inside another route

```
render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      {/* make them children of `App` */}
      <Route path="/repos" component={Repos}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

Add `{this.props.children}`

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>React Router Tutorial</h1>
        <ul role="nav">
          <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/repos">Repos</Link></li>
        </ul>

        {/* add this */}
        {this.props.children}

      </div>
    )
  }
```

After those steps, When I click a link on `About` or `Repos`, I don't go to new screen but it will render in same screen. I don't understand logic here. Why React Router will render in same screen if I can do 2 above steps. Please explain for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is to reduce repetition, by showing elements, which should appear on every child route. In your case it is navigation. What do you prefer -- having to add navigation on every page manually or having it added automatically to every child route?

How React is achieving it is via children props, as official React docs say:

> In JSX expressions that contain both an opening tag and a closing tag,
>   the content between those tags is passed as a special prop:
>   props.children.

If you want to avoid this behavior, either you should avoid nesting or you can remove navigation from the App component and make it a separate component. Then you can include it in each child component one by one.